# C: Using Select to monitor two sockets

Tags: c, sockets, select, server

I am writing a server that connects to multiple clients.  At the moment, I am using accept on a SOCK_STREAM socket to connect new clients.  I want to be able to accept queries from clients that send a data gram to the server's SOCK_DGRAM socket.  As accept just hangs until a client sends a request to connect to that socket, I need a way to monitor both sockets until one receives a request from a client and then to be able to deal with that request and return to monitoring the sockets. I do not need the requests to be handled immediately (i.e. if a client sends a query after another client requests to connect the querying client will have to wait for the server to finish the connecting client's request and vice-versa).  I know that socket can alert the server as to how many sockets are ready to read/write but how can it tell the server which socket is ready? I.e. which socket is ready to read and which is ready to write? Here is my attempt where I know listener always needs a write after connecting and udpSock always needs a read.

```
 while(1){
        retval = select(max,&readSockSet, &writeSockSet, NULL, &timeout);
        if(retval){
            if(FD_ISSET(listener, &writeSockSet))
                printf("Client requesting to connect...\n");
            if(FD_ISSET(udpSock, &readSockSet))
                printf("Client query incoming...\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than blocking on `accept()`, you use `select()` to tell you when a client is pending so you can then call `accept()` without blocking.  Then you can monitor the TCP and UDP sockets at the same time.  The code you have is already on the right track for exactly that task, however you are using the *writing* fdset to detect when to call `accept()` when you should be using the *reading* fdset instead, and you are not resetting the fdsets or timeout on each loop iteration as `select()` modifies them.

Try this:

```
fd_set readSockSet;
timeval timeout;
int smax = max(listener, udpSock);

while (1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readSockSet);
    FD_SET(listener, &readSockSet);
    FD_SET(udpSock, &readSockSet);
    // add connected TCP clients, if needed...

    timeout.tv_sec = ...;
    timeout.tv_usec = ...;

    retval = select(smax+1, &readSockSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (retval > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(listener, &readSockSet))
        {
            printf("TCP Client requesting to connect...\n");
            // call accept() and do something with the client socket ...
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(udpSock, &readSockSet))
        {
            printf("UDP Client query incoming...\n");
            // call recv()/read() to read the datagram ...
        }

        // check connected TCP clients, if needed...
    }
    else if (retval < 0)
    {
        // check errno/WSAGetLastError(), call perror(), etc ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however now I am having an issue where once a client connects select seems to ignore the timeout and will repeatedly execute the commands in the relevant if statement for that connection.  This is the revised code @RemyLebeau `while(1){
   timeout.tv_sec = 2;
   readSSockSet = readSockSet;
   printf("@");
   fflush(stdout);
   retval = select(max+1,&readSSockSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   if(retval){
    if(FD_ISSET(listener, &readSSockSet))
     printf("Client connection incoming...\n");

    if(FD_ISSET(udpSock, &readSSockSet))
     printf("Client query incoming...\n");
   }
  }`

Comment: Did you even try the code I gave you, exactly as I showed you? What you have commented here is NOT what I gave you.

Comment: You are not initializing the timeout fully (you are ignoring the `tv_usec` field), and you are not checking the result of `select()` correctly (`if (retval)` is true for both `> 0` and `< 0`) so you are handling successes and errors together - you need to split them up.  It sounds like `select()` is failing and you are ignoring the failure.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code verbatim and it works, I'm assuming it has to do with you calling accept, while I was only printing a message to test, leaving the client trying to connect

Comment: Yes, if you don't actually call `accept()` or `recv()` to change the socket's state, it will forever continue to satisfy the `readfds` parameter of `select()` and the timeout will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this... (since you're using C rather than C++ you can replace the vector with an array or some other C-based set-of-ints data structure; I'm leaving it as a vector in the example for better clarity)

```
int listenSock = /* the socket that you want to call accept() on */
int udpSock  = /* your UDP socket */
std::vector<int> clientSocks;  /* list of connected client sockets, initially empty */

while(1){
    int maxSock = -1;
    fd_set readSockSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSockSet);
    FD_SET(listenSock, &readSockSet);  // listenSock will be ready-for-ready when it's time to accept()
    if (listenSock > maxSock) maxSock = listenSock;

    FD_SET(udpSock, &readSockSet);  // let us know when a UDP packet arrives
    if (udpSock > maxSock) maxSock = udpSock;

    for (int i=0; i<clientSocks.size(); i++)
    {
       FD_SET(clientSocks[i], &readSockSet);
       if (clientSocks[i] > maxSock) maxSock = clientSocks[i];
    }

    struct timeout = {5, 0};  // five-second timeout, just to demonstrate
    retval = select(maxReadSock+1, &readSockSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if(retval >= 0)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(listenSock, &writeSockSet))
        {
            printf("Client requesting to connect...\n");
            struct sockaddr_in sai;
            socklen_t saiSize = sizeof(sai);
            int newClientSock = accept(listenSock, &sai, &saiSize);
            if (newClientSock >= 0) clientSocks.push_back(newClientSock);
                               else perror("accept");
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(udpSock, &readSockSet))
        {
            printf("UDP packet incoming...\n");
            char buf[2000];
            int numBytesReceived = recv(udpSock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            if (numBytesReceived >= 0) 
            {
               printf("Received %i-byte UDP packet!\n", numBytesReceived);
            }
            else perror("recv(UDP)");
        }

        // iterate backwards in case we need to remove a disconnected client socket
        for (int i=clientSocks.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
           if (FD_ISSET(clientSocks[i], &readSockSet))
           {
               printf("TCP data incoming from socket #%i...\n", clientSocks[i]);
               char buf[2000];
               int numBytesReceived = recv(clientSocks[i], buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
               if (numBytesReceived > 0) 
               {
                  printf("Received %i bytes of TCP data from client socket #%i!\n", numBytesReceived, clientSocks[i]);
               }
               else 
               {
                  if (numBytesReceived == 0) printf("Client with socket #%i disconnected.\n", clientSocks[i]);
                                        else perror("recv(TCP)");
                  close(clientSocks[i]);
                  clientSocks.erase(i); // remove closed socket at position i
               }
           }
        }
    }
    else perror("select");
}
```

Comment: You are testing the result of `select()` for `>= 0`, but 0 means timeout so NONE of the sockets will have anything to act on, so you should be testing for `> 0` instead.  Also, don't forget that `select()` has a max limit on the number of sockets it can monitor simultaneously.  If you have more clients connected than `select()` can handle, you have to make multiple calls to `select()` with different fdset lists, or switch to `(e)poll().

Comment: The logic works fine with testing for >=0 also, it's just a little bit less efficient.  The upside is that there is one less data-path to handle -- instead of handling (the sockets-ready case, the timeout-case, and the error-case), you only have to handle (the error-case and the no-error case).

Comment: I did not say that it would not work, but when the result is 0 then all of the `FD_ISSET()` checks will return FALSE since `readSockSet` will be empty, so it is just wasted overhead. If you don't need to handle the timeout, you simply would not write any code path for it, so you still have just an error case and a no-error case .

Answer (score 0):

Select function for sockets usually has an optional parameter to limit the amount of time you block on the socket or list of socket.

In php and ruby select() can watch a list of sockets